# JSON Cross-site scripting limitation

Tags: jquery, json, cross-site

I have a json file at http://www.example.com/file.json. I am calling it with this function but it's not working.I can not see what is wrong with it. The file is there at the proper location and I can view it.

```
function privateyStandards(){
    var callSite = "http://www.example.com/file.json";
    var privateStandards = {
        "cache":  false,
        // Use JSONP to work around cross-site scripting limitations.
        "dataType":  "jsonp",
        "url":  callSite
    };
    var privateRequest = $.ajax(privateStandards);
    privateRequest.done(function(data){
        console.log('enter');
        //does not enter
    });
}
```

Here is what is in the JSON file

```
{
  "copy":"2014",
  "itemprop":"Title",
  "privacyStatement":"URL",
  "identityStandards":"URL",
  "usePolicy":"URL",
  "casIT":"URL"
}
```

UPDATE

apsillers is correct, I changed the JSON file and the call to the json file accordingly.

```
                    function privateyStandards(){
                    var callSite = "http://www.example.com/file.json";
                    var privateStandards = {
                        "cache":  false,
                        // Use JSONP to work around cross-site scripting limitations.
                        "dataType":  "jsonp",
                        "url":  callSite,
                        async: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                        dataType: 'jsonp'
                    };
                    var privateRequest = $.ajax(privateStandards);
                        privateRequest.done(function(data){
                            alert(data.copy);
                        });
                }
```

And in the json file I changed to this

```
jsonCallback(
  {
   "copy":"2014",
   "itemprop":"Title",
   "privacyStatement":"URL",
   "identityStandards":"URL",
   "usePolicy":"URL",
   "casIT":"URL"
 }
);
```

Comment: Is the site designed to be called in JSONP ? The URL makes that doubtful.

Comment: Do you have errors in the console (F12) ?

Comment: Do you understand how JSONP works? The contents of `file.json` must be a JavaScript script file. Is it a script file, or is it merely a JSON data file?

Comment: you must declare the type and/or datatype property on the ajax call